# how to manage logback logging levels with springboot app

Tags: logging, spring-boot, logback

I have a springboot app where i have placed logback.xml @ app/src/main/resources/logback.xml. My application picks it up and I am able to see the logs as configured in logback.xml

### Issue:

I use maven to build my springboot app and logback.xml gets embedded to app.jar . There is no way I can have handle to change the logging level.
My logback.xml has a lot of configuration which unfortunately I do not think I can  manage with spring logging.* properties.

Would like to know how you guys manage logging level with springboot app.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle logging level in application.properties in Spring Boot like below:

```
logging.level.com.test=DEBUG
logging.level.org=INFO
```

Comment: logback.xml will override the application.properties. If I am not using logback.xml not sure how to handle appender with rollingpolicy in application.properties

Comment: logback.xml  can be used for logging as per spring profile ..  <springProfile name="PROD">
        <logger name="com.test" level="ERROR"/>
    </springProfile>.. You  can use either or both approaches and check your logging ..